# Assembly Language, objdump?

Tags: disassembly, objdump

I'm trying to follow along in the Art of Exploitation book, yet when I got to the disassembly language portion I got a little lost, because my output after running the `objdump -D a.out | grep -A20 main.:` command that he wrote was different.

```
08048374 <main>:
8048374: 55____     push %ebp
8048375: 89 e5    __mov %esp,%ebp
8048377: 83 ec 08 sub $0x8,%esp
```

Mine looked like:

```
0000000000400530 <main>:
400530:  55        _____push %rbp
400531:  48 89 e5  mov  %rsp, %rbp
```

Frankly I have no clue as to what is going on, anyone have better resources I could look to on the internet?  Or a source that would explain to me little things like what the -d after objdump does?  Google searches for arguments like `-d` or `-l` yields few results.

Comment: Just do `gobjdump --help`, it will tell you what the arguments are.

Comment: Well one glaring difference is that the second version appears to be 64bit code and the first appears to be 32bit. Without seeing the compiled program it is hard to tell. Other differences could be calling convention and/or optimizations.

Comment: So effectively I think to produce similar results your problem likely begins with compiling as 32bit instead of 64bit. If you This in itself might be the difference. If it isn't then the compiler flags may be different (optimizations etc). I don't think the issue is in the way you are using objdump

Comment: What does rbp/rsp mean?  More registry's?

Comment: `rbp` and `rsp` are 64bit register counterparts to the 32bit `ebp` and `esp` registers. `esp` and `rsp` are stack pointer registers and `ebp` and `rbp` are used as stack frame pointers (generally used to unwind the stack after a function call).

Comment: Might you know of any resources to learn about all this?